# What classical piece is used as inspiration during the first six seconds of Purple Dreams by Figaro Castello?

Tags: history

I think the artist Figaro Castello borrowed a motif from a famous romantic era piece in his piano composition "Purple Dreams". [Spotify link](https://open.spotify.com/album/5cRBmAwNq5JBzSICYNMjr6).

What is the name of the piece it is alluding to? It is repeated throughout the track but can be heard in the first six seconds.

Comment: You might try [musicfans.se], where this would be more on topic. You also may consider finding another place to listen to it, since (at least on my end) you have to sign up for Spotify to hear it.

Comment: @GabrielFair Do you have a link to a free recording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is the Toccata and Fugue in D minor, by Bach. I have played the piece quite a bit and recognized it immediately!

https://youtu.be/Nnuq9PXbywA?t=152

Answer (score 4):

I though it was a classical piece but after some investigating I found it sounds like he heavily borrowed from the song "Chateau Ladutorm" from a 1986 NES Video Game called "Dragon Warrior". I remember playing this game as a kid and the first time I heard "Purple Dreams" I thought it was a remake of the theme from "Dragon Warrior".

Title: Chateau Ladutorm

Composer: Koichi Sugiyama

Arranger: Takenori Yamamori

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jly1zTJDRXM

OR

http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php/Dragon_Warrior_(NES)#Albums  Track 2

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Quest_(video_game)

Answer (score 1):

It reminded me of Faithless "[Drifting away](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdFgYwRsdS4)", which uses a sample of L'altra notte in fondo al mare from [Mefistofele](https://www.faust.com/music/opera/mefistofele/)

Answer (score 1):

Passacaglia - Secret garden sounds somewhat the same

Comment: could you pls add link to YT video of the music, ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than Bach's *Toccato and Fugue*, it seems to be inspired by *Passacaglia* by [Handel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Frideric_Handel) & [Halvorsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Halvorsen).

- [Here's a version on the violin and cello](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNsxXued784), by [Julia Fischer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Fischer) and [Daniel Müller-Schott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_M%C3%BCller-Schott). In particular, listen from [2:06](https://youtu.be/qNsxXued784?t=126) onwards.
- [Here's a piano cover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDmw65QvlQQ) of the same piece. I think the motif is clearer for some in this version.